# How to convert reset procedure from Sun Pascal to Free Pascal?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have a pascal program which is compiled using Sun pascal 2.1, and I want to compile it by fpc now, but I got in some trouble. Reset procedure is used in that program but
Sun Pascal's reset: reset(file,filename), where *filename* is a string(See Sun Pascal 3.0.2 Reference Manual);
while FPC's reset: 
procedure Reset(
  var f: file;
  l: LongInt
);(http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/reset.html), so I got "incompatible type" error.

In my case, reset's 2nd parameter is an array of char, is it OK to just change it to reset(file, sizeof(array)), or should I choose anther compiler, like gpc, in which I found the 2nd parameter of reset is also string.

Comment: Why not abandon Pascal IO and use streams or some such.

Comment: In FreePascal, that is probably `Assign(f, filename); Reset(f);`. The `l` is the record size assumed, and can be omitted (see the second form of `Reset()` at the link you posted). Other Pascals probably don't use `Assign()`. Oh, instead of `Assign()`, you *might* have to use `AssignFile()` instead, like in Delphi. **But I think it would be better to heed @DavidHeffernan's advice and to use (file)streams instead. They are well documented and far easier to use.**

Comment: FWIW, in Delphi and probably in FreePascal too, `file` is a reserved word (like `string`), i.e. you can not use it as a variable name.

Comment: Florian added an overload in FPC trunk (when using ISO mode). But it won't be generally available in the next major version (3.2 or 4.0)

Comment: To clearify Marco's comment: it will be available with the next major version of FPC, but only in ISO mode, not in other modes.

Answer (score 0):

Start here:

http://wiki.freepascal.org/File_Handling_In_Pascal

But I second the motion to use more modern ways with streams and/or Stringlists.

Comment: Please don't post offsite links without at least repeating the relevant content in your answer. Offsite links can become invalid (and often do, after some years).

Answer (score 0):

An alternatives is Modern Pascal's CLI (www.ModernPascal.com). I wrote it to migrate Apple Pascal, and old Turbo Pascal to work on modern platforms. I support 99% of the older syntax, along with Web, dBase, etc. (I port legacy solutions to Linux, Mac, etc. this way).

Comment: IMHO: StringLists - they are a kludge and cannot work with stored pascal records. Streams is like adding 20 lines of code to do what you did in 2 - in most legacy cases.